# Error al instalar React Native

Tags: react-native

Hola les pratico mi problema,

estoy intetnado instalar React Native en Ubuntu/linux GNU, en la documentation dice que se asume que tienes instalado Node JS en tu sistema como comentan aqui :

*Assuming that you have Node installed, you can use npm to install the create-react-native-app command line utility:*

y si tengo instalado Node JS como ven en mi terminal :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven tengo la version :

```
 v0.8.21
```

ejecuto el comando :

```
 npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

para instalar el create-react-native-app como dice en su documentacion.

cuando intento crear una aplicacion de ejemplo me salta este error:

```
root@sommer0123-AO532h:~# npm install -g create-react-native-app
▄ ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine create-react-native-app@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=6"} (current: {"noloadRequestedDeps         ▐ ╢██████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine create-react-native-app@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=6"} (current: {"no/usr/local/bin/create-react-native-app -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-native-app/build/index.js
/usr/local/lib
└─┬ create-react-native-app@1.0.0 
  ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.26.0 
  │ ├── core-js@2.5.3 
  │ └── regenerator-runtime@0.11.1 
  ├─┬ chalk@2.3.0 
  │ ├─┬ ansi-styles@3.2.0 
  │ │ └─┬ color-convert@1.9.1 
  │ │   └── color-name@1.1.3 
  │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 
  │ └─┬ supports-color@4.5.0 
  │   └── has-flag@2.0.0 
  ├─┬ cross-spawn@5.1.0 
  │ ├─┬ lru-cache@4.1.1 
  │ │ ├── pseudomap@1.0.2 
  │ │ └── yallist@2.1.2 
  │ ├─┬ shebang-command@1.2.0 
  │ │ └── shebang-regex@1.0.0 
  │ └─┬ which@1.3.0 
  │   └── isexe@2.0.0 
  ├─┬ fs-extra@4.0.3 
  │ ├── graceful-fs@4.1.11 
  │ ├── jsonfile@4.0.0 
  │ └── universalify@0.1.1 
  ├── minimist@1.2.0 
  ├── path-exists@3.0.0 
  ├── semver@5.4.1 
  └─┬ source-map-support@0.4.18 
    └── source-map@0.5.7 

root@sommer0123-AO532h:~# create-react-native-app AwesomeProject

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-native-app/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js:3
const assign = require('./util/assign')
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-native-app/build/index.js:233:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

El comando que uso para crear la aplicacion es esta :

```
 create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de que hize mal?

Answer (score 3):

La version del **Node** tiene que ser mayor o igual a 6 para poder usar `create-react-native-app`.

> Necesitará tener Node v6 o posterior en su máquina. Recomendamos utilizar npm v3, v4 o una versión reciente de Yarn. La aplicación Create React Native actualmente no funciona con npm v5 debido a errores en npm

Fuente: [react-community](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app)

Eso te lo dice en la linea:

```
 WARN engine create-react-native-app@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=6"} (current: 
 {"noloadRequestedDeps         ▐ 
 ╢██████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
 WARN engine create-react-native-app@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=6"} (current: 
 {"no/usr/local/bin/create-react-native-app -> 
 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-native-app/build/index.js
```

> "node":">=6"

y tu version es

> v0.8.21

Cambia o instala de nuevo **Node** e intenta de nuevo saludos.